# Is luwak production ready?

Tags: riak, riak-cs

I'm implementing a blob store over Riak KV to make an experiment storing mail attachment.  Riak CS seems over reaching for this goal.

I already have a [prototype implemented in Python](https://github.com/mvaled/kaircs) and many ideas to keep working on it.  Today I stumbled upon [luwak](https://github.com/basho/luwak), which has a similar design, however much more complete and consistent with the Merkle tree metadata.

Is luwak abandoned in favor of Riak CS? Is it production ready?

Comment: Googling for "luwak riak abandoned" did not yield the post given in the answer.  Now this question appears in my searches.  I only asked it because, beside the old commits (which may happen for very stable libraries) I had no other trustworthy indication of abandonment.

Comment: FYI (I didn't downvote you or vote to close) the search term I used was simply "luwak riak" - it was the third item down for me.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  I put an [issue](https://github.com/basho-labs/luwak/issues/24) and now the repository itself states its status.  Which is IMO more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like it has been abandoned](http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2011-December/006905.html):

> Hi all,
>   I wanted to take a moment and let the community-at-large know
>   that we are going to end-of-life the Luwak functionality in Riak, as
>   part of our 1.1 release in February. This simply means that the Luwak
>   repo on Github will not be actively developed/supported by Basho, or
>   included as a default Riak dependency. In keeping with our commitment
>   to Open Source, the code will still be available if someone else wants
>   to develop on it. You can also continue to use it with Riak if you are
>   willing to edit the deps and compile from source -- the Luwak README
>   will contain information on how to do this.
>   While the idea of Luwak
>   was interesting, we ultimately decided that it wasn’t the
>   architectural path we wanted to pursue for storing larger values in
>   Riak. If Luwak is a piece of your Riak deployment, we’d love to hear
>   from you and incorporate your feedback into future directions.
>   Please don’t hesitate to reach out to myself or Mark Phillips.
>   Thanks, D.

The last commit on the open-source project was a little over 3 years ago, and it's had [an outstanding pull request open for 10 months](https://github.com/basho/luwak/pull/23) (the comments on there are not encouraging either). So yeah, I'd say it's pretty dead.